# Мерцание View после анимации Android

Tags: android

Имеется `RelativeLayout` и `ImageView`.
Для них одновременно запускаются анимации:

Для `RelativeLayout` :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="2.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:duration="500">
</scale>
```

Для `ImageView` :

```
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="500">
</scale>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="-44.5%p"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="500">
</translate>
```

После окончания анимации появляется сильное мерцание их вьюхи.
Пробовал `clearAnimation();` и `setFillBefore(true)` , и `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` но ничего не помогло.
Знает Кто решение?

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    back = 2;

    animationLay = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.toolbar_up);
    layoutDelete.startAnimation(animationLay);

    animationImg = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.delete);
    imgDelete.startAnimation(animationImg);


    animationImg.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onAnimationStart");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onAnimationEnd");

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams l = imgDelete.getLayoutParams();
            int w = imgDelete.getWidth();
            int h = imgDelete.getHeight();
            l.height = w + w;
            l.width = h + h;
            imgDelete.setLayoutParams(l);

            layoutDelete.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onAnimationRepeat");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавил в `onAnimationEnd` небольшую анимацию для обоих вьюшек. Все работает плавно

```
 @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onAnimationEnd");

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams l = imgDelete.getLayoutParams();
                int w = imgDelete.getWidth();
                int h = imgDelete.getHeight();
                l.height = w / 2;
                l.width = h / 2;
                imgDelete.setLayoutParams(l);

                animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                animation.setDuration(1);
                imgDelete.startAnimation(animation);

                animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                animation.setDuration(1);
                layoutDelete.startAnimation(animation);

                layoutDelete.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

            }
```